# Lenovo Carbon X1 3rd gen Windows 10 upgrade to a Samsung 860 evo M.2 1TB SSD problems

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, ssd, lenovo-laptop

**TL;DR -** Windows 10 suddenly considers a new Samsung 860 evo drive through USB to be "write protected". How can I undo that?

**Details:**

Lenovo X1 carbon 3rd generation here with a Samsung 250GB M.2 SSD. Need more space. Bought a 1TB Samsung 860 evo with 1TB, M.2 of course and SATA because the 3rd gen X1 can't do the NVMe.

We are on Windows 10 here. And I have done similar things many times, including when I first got this laptop. I have copied the disk at least 3 times migrating between hardware, I hate "installing Windows" and it's not necessary.

Usually I just boot FreeBSD from memory stick, use some USB to SATA adapter, and just dd the entire raw disk image over to the new media and swap the media out. Have done this dozens of times. This time I thought, what the heck, let's use cygwin dd for that. Start cygwin shell as admin and type:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=100M status=progress
```

Made the raw disk copy. But then I decided (perhaps wrongly) to see if I can also run checkdisk on the cloned NTSF volume to account for the fact that I just copied a live mounted volume. That's where things went sour.

After cloning then unplugging and re-plugging the new drive The partition control panel in Windows 10 now showed the drive with the same partition layout as Disk 1 same as my main drive (Disk 0). It showed a warning saying Disk 1 is "Offline" because it has the same id as Disk 0, of course, it's a clone. But to run checkdisk on the NTSF partition I needed to put it online. So I did and a drive letter was assigned, I ran checkdisk and then removed the drive and shut down. Swapped the old internal M.2 stick with this new one and started.

A blue screen showed:

[image]

Error 0xc000000e. And I look up and it has something to do with the boot content not properly found. I go through the possible explanations:

1. Drive physically not interoperable with the internal slot of the X1 3rd gen? -- No! Because that blue screen is a Windows thing and must come from this drive, not bootable would have just gone back to BIOS.
2. Somehow my "Online" and checkdisk and drive letter assignment rendered the boot NTSF volume permanently with the drive letter D: so the second pass boot loader could not find it.
3. Some more complicated stuff, unlikely.

Now I swapped the old drive back in, booted the laptop without problems, and now I wanted to undo the drive letter assignment stuff by just copying the drive again. But that started to fail. I tried to set the Drive 1 "Offline" again on the partition manager, unplugged it and re-plugged it, and now it shows all partitions gone now. OK, no problem, let's just take this thing Offline again and clone again. But here is what happenes:

[image]

results in "The media is write protected".

[image]

Huh? Why is it suddenly write protected? Indeed my dd also fails:

```
$ dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=100M status=progress 
dd: error writing '/dev/sdb': Read-only file system
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
4294967295 bytes (4.3 GB, 4.0 GiB) copied, 0.385278 s, 11.1 GB/s
```

**What is this "write protection" suddenly? How can I undo that?**

The new drive did not break, I can still read from it with dd. But it's partitioning is gone and it cannot be taken offline nor initialized now written to raw.

Unfortunately my little memory stick broke so that I can't just boot to FreeBSD right now and fix it for me again, so I don't know if that also would somehow consider this drive write protected now.

Any idea how I can reset this drive and start over from scratch?

Comment: This is a very long post and not everything in the post has to do with the drive. You said your Generation 3 X1 cannot do NVMe.  Did you change the drive to a compatible drive?

Comment: @John I didn't buy an NVMe drive in the first place.

Comment: Then get the Lenovo Recovery USB key for your machine and reinstall with the Lenovo Key. I have done this before and it works.

Comment: @John what "Lenovo Key"? The laptop works and I don't need to reinstall anything.

Comment: @John the issue is right now I can't write to that new drive through the USB adapter. Windows has decided it's write protected, and there is no mechanical switch of any kind that I accidentally flipped.

Comment: You asked "How do I reset this drive" - I use a Lenovo Recovery USB key to do this.

Comment: You can make a Recovery Key from your own system if you wish (as you said) to reset the drive and the key you make will boot and let you recover    https://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/solutions/ht035659-how-can-i-create-recovery-media-dvd-or-usb-or-order-recovery-media-dvd-or-usb-from-lenovo

Comment: Have you tried using `diskpart` to remove the read only attribute?  Run diskpart, select your disk.. then `attributes disk clear readonly`.  Might work.. might not but shouldn't hurt anything.

Answer (score 1):

Few things you can try

---

Remove disk write protection using CMD

1. Hit `Windows Key + X` on your keyboard, and select Command Prompt (Admin) from the menu.
2. Type `diskpart` and press Enter.
3. Type `list disk` and press Enter.
4. Type `select disk` #(ex: Disk 1) to select the disk which is write protected and press Enter.

> you see the present attributes by typing `attributes disk`

5. Type `attributes disk clear readonly` to change the disk’s properties so that it is no longer read-only and press Enter.
6. Type `exit` and press Enter twice to exit Diskpart and Command Prompt continuously. Re-plug your USB flash drive to check if the write protection error is solved.

[image]

---

Disable write protection by editing the registry

1. Press Windows Key + R to open the Run dialogue. Type regedit and press Enter or click “OK” to open the Registry Editor.
2. Expand the entries on the left-hand pane to navigate to the following path:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control

> Look for a value named `WriteProtect` in
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies`
> . If it exists, delete it. If it does not exist, you can either copy it from
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies` or    continue following from step 3.
> **If the “WriteProtect” value does not exist in either location, this
> security setting may not be your issue.**

3. Right click the Control (folder) key, select New, and click on Key. Name the new key `StorageDevicePolicies`.

[image: New Key]

4. Select the newly created key, and right click on the white space at the right-hand pane. Select New, and click on DWORD (32-bit) Value. Name the new DWORD WriteProtect.

[image: New DWORD]

5. Double click the newly created DWORD and change its value from 1 to 0. Click “OK” to apply the change.

[image: Value Data]

Tips: 1 means “Yes, write protect my USB storage devices.” Conversely, 0 means “No, don’t write protect my USB storage devices.”

6. Close Registry Editor and restart your computer.

Comment: seems like the OP  has already solved the issue but since i was already in mid of posting it so i will leave it here for others who may it helpful

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how that read only attribute was set, but it seems some Windows only issue.

I did end up booting into FreeBSD from memory stick, which was only possible after I turned off UEFI Secure Boot in the BIOS and allowed for Legacy Boot there. Then I did my normal procedure which in this case was:

```
dd if=/dev/ada0 of=/dev/da1 bs=100M status=progress
```

(of course you have to painstakingly make sure you have your device names identified to not by accident destroy your last working copy of the disk!!!)

and then I repaired the GEOM label with

```
gpart repair /dev/da1
```

which backs up the master partition table in the last sector of the drive. Once that was done, installed the new 1TB drive as the internal one, and the system booted right up into Windows 10 as it did from the old drive.